# ko.computed with observablearray values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to ko.compute two values within observables arrays. Is this even possible with Knockout?

What I'm wanting to do is something like this:

```
viewModel.visibleGarment = ko.computed(function () {
        return viewModel.selectedGarment().garmentName + '' + viewModel.selectedGarment().garmentType;
    });
```

I'm new to Knockout so what I'm trying to do may not be correct. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: What is the observable array in your sample? selectedGarment? garmentName? garmentType? What should be the expected output of the visibleGarment? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi. I've done a fiddle of what I am working on. You can see I'm trying to output visibleGarment in the HTML which is computed from some observables. http://jsfiddle.net/SV4cL/2/